In an obtuse triangle show that $c+h > a+b$ if the angle is at C.
Consider a triangle $ABC$ with an obtuse angle at vertex $C$. Let the lengths of the sides adjacent to $C$ be $a$ and $b$, and the length of the side opposite $C$ be $c$. The height from $C$ to $AB$ has length $h$. For a positive real number $p$, investigate whether the inequality
$$
c + p h > a + b
$$
holds for all obtuse-angled triangles:
a) Show that the inequality holds for $p = 1$.
I tried to use the law of cosines to get:
$$c = \sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab\cos C} > \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$, since $C>90°$, so thes cosine is negative.
And then to get $h$ I used the area of the triangle with: $$\frac{1}{2}hc = \frac{abc}{4R} \Leftrightarrow h = \frac{ab}{2R}$$, but I could not finish it.
I would be really grateful for any hints or the solution.
Thank you very much in advance.

I think for $p=1$, a possible computation is as follows:
Since $a,b,c,h$ are positive numbers, we have
$$c+h >a+b \Leftrightarrow c^2 +2ch+h^2 > a^2+b^2+2ab. \quad (1)$$
By the Law of cosines:  $$ 2ab\cos(C) = a^2 +b^2-c^2$$
On the other hand, the area $S$ of the triangle $AB$ is given by $S= \frac{ch}{2} =  \frac{ab\sin(C)}{2}$, which means $ch = ab\sin(C)$. Thus inequality $(1)$ can be reduced to prove
$$h^2 > 2ab\cos(C) +2ab-2ab\sin(C) = 2ab\left(\cos(C) - \sin(C)+1\right) \quad (2)$$
As $C \in (\pi/2,\pi)$, it is easy to show that $\cos(C)-\sin(C)+1 < 0$, hence the inequality $(2)$ is true for obtuse angle $C$.


Comment: Considering the figure we can observe that $c+h>a+b$, also:
In $\triangle CHI:(CB= a)<HI$
In $\triangle AHC: b<HA+h$
Summing these relations we get:
$a+b<(HI+HA)+h$
$HI+HA=c$
$\Rightarrow a+b<c+2h$
It is possible that $a+b=c+h$, following figure shows it happens when triangle is acute:
